# Why Bootstrap autocomplete Select not working correctly?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to get Bootstrap/jQuery autocomplete to work. With the help of @ Rav most os it works apart from the ' `select: function( event, ui ) {`'. When the user starts to enter text in to the '`#client_name`' text field, after three charatcoes a list of possible options appears.

One of the options is selected, that works, but then I need to populate '`$('#company_image_1')`'.

The Ajax return looks like this:

```
["BRITA|Brita.png|LONHA","Britannia|BrittaniaPharmaceuticals.png|","Britannia Pharmaceuticals Ltd|Britannia_1.png|GILHR","British Airports Authority|baa.png|LHRPQ"]
```

The code below is what I am trying:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#LookUpCompanyImage").html('');
    $('#client_name').autocomplete({
      minLength: 3,
      appendTo: "#suggestion_container",
      "position": { my : "right top", at: "right bottom", collision: "flip" },
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url : 'check_name.php',
          type: "get",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            name_startsWith: request.term,
            row_num : 1
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
              var code = item.split("|");
              console.log("CODE", code);
              return {
                label: code[0],
                value: code[0],
                data : item
              };
            }));
          },
          autoFocus: true,

         select: function( event, ui ) {
           var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
           $('#company_image_1').val(names[1]);
           $("#LookUpCompanyImage").html("<img src=\"../../../../../apps/conf/conf_images/adminsmall/" + names[1] + "\">");
         }
       }
     );
    }
  });
});
```

Can anyone see why the '`$('#company_image_1').val(names[1]);`' is not populated.

Comment: What does `ui` return if you `console.log` it?

Comment: @Gary Thomas I have now inserted select: function( event, ui ) {
 console.log("UI", ui);
   var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
      $('#company_image_1').val(names[1]);
      $("#LookUpCompanyImage").html("<img src=\"../../../../../apps/conf/conf_images/adminsmall/" + names[1] + "\">");
    }, but there is no error. So I then inserted  select: function( event, ui ) {
 console.log("TEST");, even that does not display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not ended your `source` property properly. This means the `select` and `autoFocus` properties meant to be declared as parameters of `autocomplete`, are actually being declared inside your `ajax` function.

The syntax should be as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#LookUpCompanyImage').html('');
  $('#client_name').autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    appendTo: '#suggestion_container',
    position: { my: 'right top', at: 'right bottom', collision: 'flip' },
    
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'check_name.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          name_startsWith: request.term,
          row_num: 1
        },
        success: function(data) {
          response(
            $.map(data, function(item) {
              var code = item.split('|');
              console.log('CODE', code);
              return {
                label: code[0],
                value: code[0],
                data: item
              };
            })
          );
        }
      });
    },
    
    autoFocus: true,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var names = ui.item.data.split('|');
      $('#company_image_1').val(names[1]);
      $('#LookUpCompanyImage').html(
        '<img src="../../../../../apps/conf/conf_images/adminsmall/' +
          names[1] +
          '">'
      );
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: 'Gary Thomas Many thanks for looking at this issue, it now works perfectly. I have spent all afternoon playing with the positioning of the code. But a fresh set of eyes did the trick. Agin many thanks for your time.